# Taking limits inside a Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I apologise for the imprecise title; I could not think of a better way to phrase what I would like to ask. The context is as follows: I am constructing an ODE containing, among other terms, an unknown function $p(t)$. It is to be defined on the domain $[0, s]$, with $p(s)=0$ and a one-sided (left-hand) derivative $p'(s) < \infty$.

I would like to study the behaviour of my ODE around the point $s$. Since I do not know the form of $p(t)$, I develop it around $s$ to first order, writing
$$
 p(t) = p(s) + p'(s)(t - s) = p'(s)(t - s)\ . 
$$
Now, it would simplify the form of my ODE enormously if I could work with the function $p'(t)$ instead of the constant $p'(s)$. Hence my question: is there any justification for writing, instead of the above, something like
$$
 p(t) = \left( \lim_{t\to s}p'(t) \right)(t - s)\ ,
$$
giving me the wiggle room to continue using the time-behaviour of the first derivative?

Comment: If $p'$ is continuous, then this certainly holds (by sequential continuity)

Comment: Thanks! I would accept this as an answer.